# How to get zoom out from zoomed image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have code like this..

in loadView()

I have created the scrollview like this with no.of taps and max value

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2;
self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[tapOnce setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Method implementation:

```
- (void) handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
//single tap in full screen mode it will dismiss the view
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
//double tap will zoom the view to scrollview max value
  [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:NO];   
}
```

Now I am able to "zoom" on tapping to full screen image and it will go in maxZoom value, but how to come back from zoomed to min value on double tap on the same, because I have functionality to dismiss the view on single tap. I need to handle one more double tap in the "handledoubleTap" method itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    if ( flag == 1 ){
        flag = 0;
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:NO];   
    }
    else {
        flag = 1;
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:NO];   
    }

}
```

In the above method just set flag according to your need. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thank you.. its works for me.. but i am not able to zoom the touch position, it is just zooming to max value, i need like the touch position in fullscreen should zoom... can anybody tell me how to do